# Proving all Finite sets are Non-Infinite

Tags: logic

I am trying to show by induction on N that every finite set is not infinite.
I think I have most of it and I know I need to consider some cases, but I am a little lost on how I go forward.
I know I need to use the definition is that a set A is finite iff A ≈n for some n ∈ N but im not sure exactly what to do. Below is the proof I have started.

Proof by Induction. \
Let F = {n $\in$ (N)$|$ n is not infinite}, then

\textbf{Base Case}\
The empty set has no subsets besides the empty set. As this is not a proper subset of the empty set the empty set has no proper subsets at all and thus cannot be infinite so $\emptyset \in$ F.\

\textbf{Induction Step}
Assume n is not infinite. We must show n +1 is not infinite. n + 1 = n $\cup$ {n}.\
Suppose for contradiction n + 1 is infinite. Thus there exists, A $\subset$ n $\cup$ {n}, and n $\cup$ {n} is equinumerous with A.  \
(Case 1): {n} $\in$ A.  \

(case 2): {n} $\notin$ A\

Thus now that we have shown that F = N, we know that every element in N is not infinite and thus that every finite set is not infinite. QED\

Should I choose different cases to check? My main concern is if A contains some elements of n but not all of them. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hey, welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Please use inline TeX equations to make it easier to read; see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I think you mean case 1: $n\in A$, case 2: $n\notin A$ (not $\{n\}$). Apart from this, I agree with your strategy (i.e. filling the 2 cases is feasible).

Comment: We typically say a set is infinite iff it is not finite. So with that, the claim is just a logical tautology.  Or do you maybe have a separate definition of when a set is infinite? If so, can you post that?

Comment: @Griff You should tell us more precisely what you are doing: _if I understood correctly_, you are comparing two definitions for a finite set. **1)** a set $X$  is finite **iff** there exists a bijection $X\colon n$ for some $n\in\Bbb{N}$; **2)** a set is (Dedekind-)finite **iff** there is no bijection between $X$ and any proper subset. Also I suspect that you dichotomy should be $(n\in A)$ or $(n\notin A)$.